# html banner with overlaying images and texts

Tags: html, css, image, overlay

Im looking for a way to dynamically create banners who can get placed on other pages. The banner consists a background image, two overlaying images and two text labels on top of this background image.

Is it right that I only can use absolute positioning to achieve a overlaying elements? How can I make sure, that the banner in its own gets placed relatively in the integrated page?

I guess I need to be able to place elements absolute inside a relative box. Is this possible?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: Oh man, have you considered making couple of banners and then load them on random? it will save much more time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. The containing element need to have `position:relative` and all the inner elements that you want to place need to have `position:absolute;` and also the position x and y like this: `top:10px; right:20px` or `bottom:10px; left:230px`

So for example:

CSS:

```
#banner_wrap {position:relative; width:860px; height:60px;}
#inner_element {position:absolute; top:10px; left:20px; width:40px; height:40px;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="banner_wrap">
   <div id="inner_element"></div>
</div>
```

If you want them to be dynamic then you can change the CSS for the specific page.

Comment: Perfect! I tried this before, but didn't realize that it already solved my problem because I placed the code at the beginning of the whole doc... Thanks for your answer!

Comment: i understood that you want to dynamically generate the banners  :D:D.

Comment: exactly and thats what this code does! I can dynamically add some user related info on to this banner!